# Logging to two tables with foreign key in log4net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, log4net

I log4net setup that currently logs to a table, what I want to do is have an FKID on the table that links to another table.

Are there any examples for doing this?

Example :

Log request, and response, but on logging the response, add the ID of the request that was logged.

Comment: To add the ID of the request to a second table would be a function of SQL Server.  Add a trigger on the INSERT of the first table in SQL Server to insert to the second table.  I don't think the function you want is something log4net can do, but it is a simple matter to add a trigger in the database to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So I never got to do the foreign key referencing, but what I did was store both request and response to the same table.

So there table has a request column and a response column - which is then stored, using log4net.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I also want to log to two tables and want to be able to know which records belong to each other. So instead of letting the database genereting the id for me, I have chosen to use a Guid. In my code I create a Guid and I use this Guid in both of my objects.